# Code:1000 Can't write or create a file in my app using ionic-native/file ionic 2

Tags: javascript, android, ionic2, ngcordova, ionic-native

I am now working on a hybrid app working on localization, the logic is that the user will have as an example 3 options to choose languages, I am having a node.js server on bluemix that deals with cloudant-nosql db to get on point i compare my local json file "rev" value with the other one on server if they are different then I have to overwrite the local file with the updated one, I have this result but I can't write this data to the local file, I am now working with cordova and ionic 2 ,

```
public  GetRevFromNode(SelectedLanguage,JsonDataLocal)
    {
        JsonDataLocal.subscribe(val=>{  this.LocJson=val;  })
        this.http.get('https://*********/retriev?ID=\"'+SelectedLanguage+"\"").subscribe( result=>
        { 
           if(this.LocJson['_rev']==result.json().value)
            {
                console.log("The Local Json is Updated to the latest");
                return ;
            }
            {
                console.log("Updating Json File for "+SelectedLanguage+".json .......");
                var ob=this.file.readAsText(this.file.applicationDirectory+'www/assets/i18n',"ar.json");
                ob.then(function(val){
                    console.log("ar JSON  = "+val);
                });
                this.file.createFile('file:///android_asset/www',"ess.json",true).catch(val=>{
                    console.log("Can't create because = "+JSON.stringify(val));
                });

   this.file.writeFile('file:///android_asset/www/',"index.html","\"value\":\"Please\"",{replace:true , append:false} ).catch(val=>{
                    console.log("Can't write because ="+JSON.stringify(val));
                console.log("Updating Done ...")
            }
        } );
    }
```

Tried to use this.file.appDirectory error also tried to make it implicitly like here

The error is

> uncaught promise [object Object]
>   by using stringify  {Code:1000}

but I can read normally and check if file exists normally the problem is with creating and writing

Answer (score 1):

See https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file#android-file-system-layout

The problem is that I can't write in the `applicationDirectory` path as this path read-only.